# What are the proper flags to compile c code using zlib

Tags: c, zlib

I'm trying to execute the zpipe.c file from https://zlib.net/zlib_how.html

```
gcc zpipe.c -o executable -lz
```

But I'm getting the error

```
zpipe.c:18:18: fatal error: zlib.h No such file or directory
```

I installed zlib from source following this tutorial https://geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/zlib/installation/installing_zlib_on_ubuntu_linux.php

Comment: I am confident that Ubuntu has zlib packages available.  The runtime libraries are surely installed already, but you might need to install a separate package of development components.  I urge you to install Ubuntu's pre-built package for these rather than installing from source.

Comment: If you nevertheless do install from source then you may need to provide flags to `gcc` to tell it where to look for the development components you installed -- header files and development libraries -- depending on exactly where you put them.  That would be an `-I` flag for the former and a `-L` flag for the latter, but the details would depend on exactly where you chose to install the components you built.  (You probably would not need extra flags if you installed the relevant Ubuntu package.)

Comment: The thing is that I've also installed (and uninstalled)  zlib with sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev, then tried to compile the code with gcc zpipe.c -o executable -lz . In that case, executable is made, but when I do ./executable, the exececutable does nothing, that is why I'm trying to use it directly from source.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the problem you encountered when using the Ubuntu packages reflects a flaw in those packages.  Always, *always* start with the assumption that the problem is in your own code.

Answer (score 2):

you can use pkg-config.

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs zlib
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-I/usr/local/include/`. It  could happen that you have to specify even the library's location with `-L/usr/local/lib/`.